# Calculating a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm given with the region $V$ , determined by the following surfaces:
$x^2 =y , y^2 =x ,z=0 , z=1$ and need to calculate:
$\iiint _V \frac{\sin x-\sin y}{xy+1} dx\,dy\,dz $ and to use symmetry.

I thought that what I really need to calculate is:
$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x^2} \frac{\sin x-\sin y}{xy+1} dy\,dx\,dz $ and multiply by 2.

Is it correct?

The problem is that if this is true, I can't understand how to calculate this integral...

Will someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

There is indeed a kind of symmetry involved in this problem.  The region of integration is symmetrical about the line $ \ y = x \ $ , which we can conclude from the boundary curves being those of functions which are inverses of one another in the first quadrant ( $ \ y = x^2 \ \ \text{and} \ \ y = \sqrt{x} \ $ ).

The integrand function is *anti*-symmetric about this line because of the difference between terms in the numerator:  exchanging $ \ x \ \ \text{and} \ \ y \ $ reverses the terms in the numerator, while having no effect on the denominator ( $ \frac{\sin y - \sin x}{yx + 1} \ = \ - \frac{\sin x - \sin y}{xy + 1}  $ ) .  We can also verify this by choosing lines  $ \ x + y = c \ $ for $ \ 0 \le  c \le 2 \ $ and examining the family of functions $ \ \frac{\sin x \ -  \ \sin (c-x)}{x(c-x) \ + \ 1}  $  , which are "odd" about the values $ \ x = \frac{c}{2} \ $ .

This occurs independently of the value of $ \ z \ $ , so there is *exact cancellation* between the two halves of the volume; hence, $\iiint _V \frac{\sin x-\sin y}{xy+1} dx\,dy\,dz \ = \ 0 $ for the given domain.  (Just as well, since the anti-derivative functions involved are non-elementary.)

Comment: WOW! Brilliant! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

No The region you choose is wrong ,The region is determined by$$0 \le x\le 1$$$$ x^2 \le y \le \sqrt{x} $$ $$ 0 \le z \le 1$$

To find boundary of a given region we can draw a graph in 2-D for given region then project in 3-D that  will give the boundary for given region . We can project in any direction x or y or z .

Comment: You are right, but I thought that I can use symmetry in order to calculate half of the region and then multiply by 2. never mind. The problem is now that I can't understand how to calculate this integral. Will you please help ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

No. The region is determined by $0 \le x \le 1$, $x^2 \le y \le \sqrt{x}$, $0 \le z \le 1$

Comment: You are right, but I thought that I can use symmetry in order to calculate half of the region and then multiply by 2. never mind. The problem is now that I can't understand how to calculate this integral. Will you please help ? Thanks !